# How do I return two different Views from the same Action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two views which will both use the same Controller method:

```
//webServiceController.cs

//The actual method is about 40 lines of code. Truncated for readability.
public ActionResult Index()
{
    object i = new List<WebServiceMethod>();
    i = svcService.populateList("Programs");

    return View(i);

}
```

The first view is an HTML page that displays the data in a pretty table output:

```
<% // Index.aspx %>

<table>
<tbody>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

<tr>
    <td>
        <% if (Convert.ToInt32(item.numberRequests) > 0)
        {%>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { programNumber = item.programNumber })%>
        <%} %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.programNumber) %>
    </td>
</tr>

<% } %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The second view is a quick'n'dirty conversion to JSON so that I can do magical AJAX tricks with the data:

```
<% 
    // AjaxGetServiceData.aspx

    // Convert web service response object into JSON for AJAX.
    var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    Response.Write(jss.Serialize(Model));

%>
```

I'd created a duplicate of the `Index()` method and called it `AjaxGetServiceData()`, but that defeats the purpose of MVC.

---

**Resolution:**

I didn't ask my question very well, as evidenced by a 5-10 minute discussion I just had with a coworker about this very topic. He kept asking me the same question that many users on this page asked me: "How does the controller know which view to return?" I responded, "That's what I'm trying to figure out." I was trying to get the method to return a different view (or Json output) when AJAX was the requester. A string argument in the method was my solution.

This is what I ended up using to get my desired effect:

```
public ActionResult Index(string isJSON = "no")
{

    /// ...All the code from before...

    if (isJSON == "yes")
    {
        return Json(i, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(i);
    }

}
```

Then, when I want the JSON version, in my AJAX request I specify the URL as `/MyController/Index/?isJSON=yes`

When I want my pretty table view, I just use `/MyController/`

Comment: Are you trying to **combine** these two code fragments into a single HTML page?

Comment: Is there any particular reason your view is generating JSON from the model, rather than your controller? It seems to me like you should be using `return Json(i);` for the JSON output.

Comment: No; The AJAX view is used for a whole different area of the site.

Comment: I don't think this is possible :(

Comment: How does the controller know which view to return?

Comment: @Nathan I had no idea you could do that. (I'm working on someone else's source code and I don't know ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: @Jeff Exactly. Maybe if I specified an argument in the Index method? Or is there a way to call the Index method from the AjaxGetServiceData method but still return the latter's view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    object i = new List<WebServiceMethod>();
    i = svcService.populateList("Programs");

    if (someCondition)
        return View(i);
    else
        return View("AjaxGetServiceData", i); // or whatever you called your view.aspx
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the `someCondition` would be.

Comment: What's the point of instantiating `i` and immediately freeing it by assigning `svcService.populateList()` to it, thus removing any reference to the newly created `List<WebServiceMethod>()`?

Comment: @Jake ? If you don't then how can you expect anyone else to? @David, don't get your panties in a bunch, I added the model

Comment: @David I guess I truncated too much of the code. The `populateList` line is in a `try`. When `catch` hits,`i` gets populated with an error message.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have two different purposes in which case I think you are going the right way when you talk about different controller methods.

Sure, reuse code inside each controller method but if you want a different result, use a different method and keep the controller methods simple.

Answer (score 0):

*" ...I was trying to get the method to return a different view (or Json output) when AJAX was the requester..."*

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    object i = new List<WebServiceMethod>();       
    i = svcService.populateList("Programs");       

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest == "True")
    {
        return Json(i, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
    }
    else
    {
        return View(i)
    }
}
```